# Turn div tag responsive CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm a little bad with CSS and i responsive things and i want to figure out how to turn my home page responsive...

Right now i have my home page like this when i try to resize for an IPhone 6s per example:

[Full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnDBW.png)

[Resize Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX1Tb.png)

When i put on full screen it's ok, i have the image and th button right on the center like i want the problem is with the responsivitity of them....

**CSS code**

```
.bodytodo {
background-image: url("../img/investigadores_ipb_site_5.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.caixa {
width: 100%;
margin: 7% auto;
}

.tabela{
margin-left: 35%;
}

.centro {
position: relative;
left: 45%;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
    <body class="bodytodo">
    <div class="caixa">
        <table class="tabela">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="~/dist/img/logoipbcor-copy.png" height="200" width="500" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
                <td class="centro"><a class="btn btn-default" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Entrar</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to make this responsive in order to be possible to click the button when i open this page on a phone per example....

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this in your head tag at the top of your webpage?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If not add that and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in making your website responsive, I would start by looking into media queries.

In the `<head>` of your page, you will need to add the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then in your stylesheet, you can define specific ranges for the screen sizes so that if the screen size matches the criteria you set, the rules will be applied. Otherwise, they will be ignored. Here is an example of what that looks like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @John That's wonderful, so have you given the media queries a try?